# How can I use GDI+ in ClassLibrary project in C#?

Tags: c#, graphics

I'm going to make a file .dll that contain a method to draw a line. I created a new Class Library project. But I can't use Graphics and Pen in that class. So I can't make a method to draw line. What can I do now?

Comment: you can see about [System.Drawing namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I guess you're having trouble with some basics - object orientation, references, "using" statements.  That's a little too basic for stackoverflow.  You need to get those things straight on your own, or else show more programming work that you did before hitting your problem.  I didn't downvote you, but you are probably getting downvotes because you don't really have a programming question.

Comment: I know how to use "using". But in Class Library, you can't use "System.Drawing.Drawing2D". You must Add Reference "System.Drawing" before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I can't use Graphics and Pen in that class

Yes, you can. Just add a reference to `System.Drawing.dll`, and import the `System.Drawing` namespace in your C# file (`using System.Drawing;`)

Comment: I can use System.Drawing.Drawing2D now. It's work after I add reference "System.Drawing". Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think youre after adding areference to your classlibrary. right click the project in your IDE andlook for add reference?! I'm not syre IF this is the answer bit based on your question it might be.